# batch - pass full path name as one argument

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, c#

I am writing a batch to call a .exe file which is made by C#.
However, the C# program reads one of the parameters incorrectly.

Here's my code in the batch file:

```
start "" "example.exe" %cd% para1
```

However, when the `%cd%` (current directory of the batch file) path contains spaces,
my C# exe will read the argument wrongly by shifting one argument.

Is there a way to set `%cd%` as one argument or other way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Put quotes around it:

`start "" "example.exe" "%cd%" para1`